# Rails 3 acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-commentable

I'm using acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem.

My _new.html.erb

```
<div class="adding_comment">&nbsp;</div>
<%=form_for [commentable, Comment.new], :remote => false do |f|%>
 <%=f.hidden_field :commentable_id, :value=> @post.id %><br/>
 <%=f.label :title%> :<br/>
 <%=f.text_field :title%><br/>
 <%=f.label :subject%> :<br/>
 <%=f.text_field :subject%><br/>
 <%=f.label :body%><br/>
 <%=f.text_area :body, :style=>"width:320;height:80px"%><br/><br/>
 <%=f.submit "Add comment"%>
<%end%>
```

Comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:comment][:commentable_id])
  @user_who_commented = current_user
  @comment = Comment.build_from(@post, @user_who_commented.id, "Comment!" )
 end
end
```

In my post model I've added:

```
acts_as_commentable
```

In my Post's show.html.erb:

```
<%= render :partial => "comments/new", :locals => { :commentable => @post }%><br/>
<h1>Comments</h1>
<div id="comments">
<%=render :partial => 'comments/index',:locals => {:commentable=> @post, :comments => @comments}%>
</div>
```

But after clicking "Submit" button I'm getting error:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
Request:
    {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"2GvCfaCB/qAxdh+1jJvcZ76jL9fdxP+h5qEIOClmNHk=",
 "comment"=>{"commentable_id"=>"1",
 "title"=>"et",
 "subject"=>"et",
 "body"=>"ewt"},
 "commit"=>"Add comment",
 "post_id"=>"google-search-and-search-engine-spam"}
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You try to call the #id method to a nil object. The only part where you call this #id is when you call :

@comment = Comment.build_from(@post, @user_who_commented.id, "Comment!" )

and @user_who_commented is your current_user. Are you sure there are a current_user ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it today, and write here about results.